# SpriteBuilder Swift code connections nil reference and deallocation issues

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am using Swift (XCode 7.2.1) and SpriteBuilder (1.4.9) to create a game. However I am having some problems with the creating code connections between CCB files and Swift classes. I followed the tutorials online and added a doc root var code connection name in SpriteBuilder and then set up the corresponding property in the class as a `private weak var m_myVar: MyClass!`. However whenever I try and access the property I get a `nil` reference. If I remove the `weak` attribute from the code connection then I can access the property, but I receive deallocation issues when the scene is detroyed, e.g. navigating to a new scene using the `CCDirector.shareDirector().replaceScene()` method.

In my specific case I have a `MainScene` in SpriteBuilder with the following node hierarchy within it: `CCNode` -> `CCNodeGradient` -> `Tile`. Where `Tile` a subclass of `CCNode` defined in a different CCB file and has the `doc root var` code connection name of `m_levelLabel`, which maps to the `private weak var m_levelLabel: Tile!` property of the `MainScene` class.

The `Tile` class has 2 properties `m_background` of type `CCSprite9Slice` and `m_label` of type `CCLabelTTF`, both of which are mapped to `private weak var` properties in the `Tile` Swift class.

When the `MainScene` loads I attempt to set some properties on the `m_levelLabel` using the following code:

```
internal func didLoadFromCCB() {
    m_levelLabel.setValue("2");
}
```

and `Tile.setValue` is defined in the `Tile` class as:

```
internal func setValue(value: String) {
    m_label.string = value;
}
```

But when the `setValue` method executes the `m_label` property is `nil` and so the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` occurs. This is odd as clearly my code connections in the `MainScene` class have worked fine as I was able to call `m_levelLabel.setValue`.

Interestingly if I change the properties in the `Tile` class to be defined as strong references like:

```
private var m_label: CCLabelTTF!;
```

Then the code executes fine and the value of the label is updated when the `MainScene` loads. However the app now crashes when I try and navigate away from the `MainScene` with the error `malloc: *** error for object 0x7a9f3200: pointer being freed was not allocated` which sounds like there is a problem when destroying the, now, strong properties in the `Tile` class owned by the `MainScene`.

What could be going on here? What is the correct way to define code connections in Swift? Note I receive no warnings in the console about missing code connection properties.

For reference here is the `MainScene` and `Tile` class in their entirety:

Main.swift

```
import Foundation

internal class MainScene: CCScene {

    internal func didLoadFromCCB() {
        m_levelLabel.setValue("1");
        m_progressLabel.setValue("0%");
    }

    internal func play() {
        let gameplayScene: CCScene = CCBReader.loadAsScene("Gameplay/GameplayScene");
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(gameplayScene);
    }

    internal func levelSelection() {
        print("Pressed level selection");
    }

    internal func progress() {
        print("Pressed progress button");
    }

    private weak var m_playButton: CCButton!;
    private weak var m_levelSelectionButton: CCButton!;
    private weak var m_progressButton: CCButton!;
    private weak var m_levelLabel: Tile!;
    private weak var m_progressLabel: Tile!;
}
```

Tile.swift

```
import Foundation

internal class Tile : CCNode {

    internal var value: String? {
        return m_label?.string;
    }

    internal func setValue(value: String) {
        m_label.string = value;
    }

    private weak var m_label: CCLabelTTF!;
    private weak var m_background: CCSprite9Slice!;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that for the code connections to always work they must have `internal` accessibility rather than `private`. E.g.

```
internal weak var m_label: CCLabelTTF!;
```

rather than

```
private weak var m_label: CCLabelTTF!;
```

I'm not sure why `private` works in some instances, but not in others and it's a shame that I can't properly encapsulate this data. I guess this is either due to a bug in the SpriteBuilder library or a limitation due to the Swift language.